# Cannot read property 'slug' of undefined, but absolutely exist

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, gatsby

I am trying to make a blog by using Gatsby.

I wanted to use Asciidoc instead of Markdown, so I wrote the following code concerning the official code.

```
const blogArticleTemplate = path.resolve(
  "./src/components/templates/article/index.tsx"
)
const articles = result.data.allAsciidoc.edges

if (0 < articles.length) {
  articles.forEach(( node, index ) => {
    const slug = node.pageAttributes.slug
    const previousArticle = index === 0 ? null : articles[index - 1].node.pageAttributes.slug
    const nextArticle = index === articles.length - 1 ? null : articles[index + 1].node.pageAttributes.slug

    createPage({
      slug,
      component: blogArticleTemplate,

      context: {
        slug: slug,
        previousArticle,
        nextArticle,
      },
    })
  })
}
```

but, this code isn't working. Returns the following error.

```
error "gatsby-node.js" threw an error while running the createPages lifecycle:

Cannot read property 'slug' of undefined

  33 |     articles.forEach(( node, index ) => {
> 34 |       const slug = node.pageAttributes.slug
     |                                        ^
  35 |       const previousArticle = index === 0 ? null : articles[index - 1].node.pageAttributes.slug
  36 |       const nextArticle = index === articles.length - 1 ? null : articles[index + 1].node.pageAttributes.slug
  37 |
```

The error message says that `pageAttributes` is undefined, but I have confirmed that `pageAttributes` isn't undefined.

Insert console.log (node) into my code, you can see that pageAttributes exists, as you can see.

```
[Object: null prototype] {
  node: [Object: null prototype] {
    pageAttributes: [Object: null prototype] { slug: '/test' }
  }
}
```

So, I have two questions:

- What the solution to this problem?
- Why do I get such an error?

Thanks.

Comment: Take a closer look at the output from your `console.log(node)` - is it possible that you might need to go down just one more level? `const slug = node.node.pageAttributes.slug`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing wrong the nested iterable object. You have defined `articles` but when iterating through them, `node` is not the nested object, is just the article itself, the iterable object. You need to downside one level.

Change the loop to:

```
articles.forEach(({ node } ) => {
   const slug = node.pageAttributes.slug
   // rest of the code
}
```

With the snippet above, you are destructuring the iterable object (article) to get the `node` itself. Alternatively, if you want to keep your previous structure, just access to:

```
articles.forEach(( node, index ) => {
    const slug = node.node.pageAttributes.slug
    // rest of the code
}
```

In that case, I would suggest a change of naming to:

```
articles.forEach(( article, index ) => {
    const slug = article.node.pageAttributes.slug
    // rest of the code
}
```